# Mostrar animação durante carregamento?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, imagem, carregamento

Não encontrei muito a respeito desse assunto em tutoriais, não sei se alguém mais já percebeu que serviços como o Facebook, Netflix utilizam uma especie de "load" antes de mostrar o conteúdo, ambos parecem funcionar da mesma forma, em alguns tutoriais disseram que isso é feito com a função ".load" do jQuery, mas a mesma se aplica para textos como o facebook usa? 
Segue exemplos dos dois serviços: 
Facebook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Napf2.jpg
Netflix: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMq9z.jpg

Que tipo de função é utilizado para fazer isso? Faz o carregamento do site parecer tão mais bonito.

Comment: Na verdade uma solução é explorar o CSS do Facebook, mas pode também ver aqui http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html

Comment: wow CSS é mais poderoso do que imaginei, então basicamente o conteúdo a ser carregado é verificado depois e até o mesmo estar validado essa animação é exibida? Interessante

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ao analisarmos o que ocorre com o Facebook, podemos ver que ele possui um HTML fixo da página, e continua carregando os demais itens via requisições ao server.

A imagem abaixo mostra um pouco do que é carregado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para entender melhor, aperte **ESC** quando abrir a página. Você cancelará as requisições e o layout não irá se formar.

Conforme muito bem mostrado pelo [@inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158683/mostrar-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-durante-carregamento#comment326800_158683) nos comentários, o layout padrão do Facebook é fácil de montar apenas com Html + css, [conforme este link](http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html) mostra (não idêntico, mas da para entender).

Abaixo eu irei mostrar um exemplo prático de como fazer isso (sem a requisição no server, é claro).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    AlteraTimeline();
  }, 3000);
});

function AlteraTimeline() {
  $('#timeline').hide();
  $('body').append('<img src="http://www.creativebeacon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/free-facebook-timeline-psd-2.jpg"/>');
}
```

```css
.background-masker {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
/* Every thing below this is just positioning */

.background-masker.header-top,
.background-masker.header-bottom,
.background-masker.subheader-bottom {
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  right: 0;
  height: 10px;
}
.background-masker.header-left,
.background-masker.subheader-left,
.background-masker.header-right,
.background-masker.subheader-right {
  top: 10px;
  left: 40px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 10px;
}
.background-masker.header-bottom {
  top: 18px;
  height: 6px;
}
.background-masker.subheader-left,
.background-masker.subheader-right {
  top: 24px;
  height: 6px;
}
.background-masker.header-right,
.background-masker.subheader-right {
  width: auto;
  left: 300px;
  right: 0;
}
.background-masker.subheader-right {
  left: 230px;
}
.background-masker.subheader-bottom {
  top: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}
.background-masker.content-top,
.background-masker.content-second-line,
.background-masker.content-third-line,
.background-masker.content-second-end,
.background-masker.content-third-end,
.background-masker.content-first-end {
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 6px;
}
.background-masker.content-top {
  height: 20px;
}
.background-masker.content-first-end,
.background-masker.content-second-end,
.background-masker.content-third-end {
  width: auto;
  left: 380px;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  height: 8px;
}
.background-masker.content-second-line {
  top: 68px;
}
.background-masker.content-second-end {
  left: 420px;
  top: 74px;
}
.background-masker.content-third-line {
  top: 82px;
}
.background-masker.content-third-end {
  left: 300px;
  top: 88px;
}
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -468px 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 468px 0
  }
}
.animated-background {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: #f6f7f8;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
  background-size: 800px 104px;
  height: 96px;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline-item {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 472px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="timeline-wrapper" id="timeline">
  <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="animated-background">
      <div class="background-masker header-top"></div>
      <div class="background-masker header-left"></div>
      <div class="background-masker header-right"></div>
      <div class="background-masker header-bottom"></div>
      <div class="background-masker subheader-left"></div>
      <div class="background-masker subheader-right"></div>
      <div class="background-masker subheader-bottom"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-top"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-first-end"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-second-line"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-second-end"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-third-line"></div>
      <div class="background-masker content-third-end"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Neste exemplpo eu tenho o layout do Facebook citado acima, e uma função para alterar o layout par auma imagem. Essa função está com um tempo de 3 segundos, apenas para dar mais realidade ao exemplo.

Comment: Muito bom uso de CSS para animações, na verdade eu tenho um carregamento muito grande de imagens na home de um projeto que estou fazendo, estou dando uma lida e mudada nesse código para chegar em algo como a Netflix.

Comment: legal mesmo ... +1

Answer (score 2):

Uma abordagem que você pode utilizar é:

Ter uma div funcionando como overlay de toda página exibindo um gif de loading.

```
<body> 
    <div class="loading"></div>
    [restante da pagina]
</body>
```

Com o auxílio do jquery, você poderá criar um "listener" para o evento de onload, quando o evento ocorrer você poderá desaparecer com a div "loading"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// windows load

   $(window).on('load', function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('.loading').removeClass('active');
      }, 300);
   });
});
```