# Como fazer a técnica de carregamento de conteúdo do Facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como o Facebook faz isto com o carregamento da sua página?
Ele carrega o conteúdo aos poucos e não tudo de uma vez como a maioria dos sites, o StackOverflow é um exemplo que carrega de vez.

- Como chama essa técnica de carregamento? (caso tiver um nome)
- Como eu posso fazê-la em JavaScript ou jQuery?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158683/5878

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando se trata de grandes empresas, como Facebook, Google, etc. é muito difícil concluir como eles fazem suas aplicações. Porém, acredito que seja algo muito parecido com a técnica *lazy load*, ou em uma tradução livre, carregamento preguiçoso. A técnica consiste em carregar os elementos da página somente quando entrarem no campo visível do usuário e, se o conteúdo for grande ou a conexão do usuário estiver lenta, o carregamento é feito de forma assíncrona. É feito uma requisição AJAX e exibe o elemento apenas quando possuir o conteúdo carregado por completo. Um cuidado que é sempre bem discutido nesse caso é de não manter a tela do usuário em branco enquanto é feita a requisição, pois o mesmo pode achar que a página não está respondendo e fechar. Para contornar isso, geralmente é exibido uma versão do conteúdo (ou genérico, no caso do Facebook) bem mais leve e o substituir quando o conteúdo em si estiver pronto.

#### Exemplo

Por exemplo, se desejar exibir uma imagem no site, mas essa imagem é gigante, 4k, com resolução 7680 × 4320, ela normalmente demorará a carregar por completo. Então podemos editar a imagem, gerando uma versão bem mais leve, de 600 × 338, reduzindo a densidade de pixels ao máximo, para que consigamos exibí-la enquanto é carregada a original. Para efeito de comparação, a imagem original possui um tamanho de 1 MB, enquanto a reduzida 8.7 kB, isto é, uma redução de 99,9913%.

```js
$(() => {
  
  var img = $("img");
  
  $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/acwoss/aeaf1264e0948bbb0965eed3e8647e31/raw/0c418cd3f4f92d8228637af34c48ed616adc4ab7/tiger4k.png", (data) => {
    img.fadeOut(400, () => {
      img.attr("src", data);
    }).fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 338px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

No exemplo acima, eu exibo a imagem de baixa resolução junto com a página, codificada na base 64 justamente para ser uma string e ser transferida junto com a página e não através de uma requisição extra. Quando todo o DOM estiver carregado, eu efetuo uma chamada assíncrona para buscar a imagem original. Quando esta estiver pronta, eu exibo-a, fazendo uma pequena animação `fade` para que a substituição não seja tão brusca.

Essa técnica é muito importante para páginas de um blog, por exemplo, pois o usuário conseguirá iniciar a leitura do texto antes que as imagens sejam carregadas e, principalmente, não haverá uma variação da posição do texto quando as mesmas forem carregadas, pois há a versão de qualidade reduzida da imagem já está na página, ocupando exatamente o espaço que a imagem original ocupará.

---

**Nota sobre *arrow functions***

A notação utilizada `() => {}` é denominada *arrow functions*, introduzida no padrão ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), e basicamente é uma nova forma para definir funções anônimas.

Fazer, no jQuery:

```
$(() => {...});
```

É o mesmo que:

```
$(function () {...});
```

Como é geralmente feito.

Se quiser ler mais sobre:

- [MDN - Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: O que `$(() => {` e `() = {` fazem? O que seriam eles?

Comment: Adicionei uma nota ao final da resposta sobre isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na realidade , há uma diferença sim... Enaqunto numa `function (){ }` o `this` refere-se à quem o enviou, numa arrow function o this vai sempre ser o objeto `window`. Há um tópico do stackoverflow aqui -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6 .

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee, Sim, de fato. Eu não quis entrar neste mérito porque na resposta nem utilizei o `this`, então elas funcionaram como funções anônimas. Passei um link para se caso o AP quisesse estudar mais, mas obrigado pelo comentário. Incorporarei seu link na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Existem varias formas de fazer isto, porem toda a pagina inicial do facebook e carregada atravez de ajax e PHP acredito eu, bom pelomenos era. Aonde de forma simplista e apenas como exemplo ele pega a div ou section que contem os posts, e caso o final dessa div `divEmSi.getBoundingClientect().bottom` seja menor que o final do interior do window `window.innerHeight + window.innerHeight / 2` obs: a soma seria para ele sempre carregar um pouco antes de chegar no final, carregue as publicações vindo em ajax do banco de dados. obviamente que eu simplifiquei um codigo extremamente gigante e com mais funcionalidades e desempenho, mais e seri basicamente isso.

Caso você esteja se referindo a animação, E tudo feito com css.

E caso esteja se referindo a lazy-loader que seria carregar qualquer conteudo somente quando estiver visivel na tela esta tecnica e chamada de Lazy-loading. Que tambem existe varias formas de fazer. Um exemplo:

```js
function lazyLoad() {
        let lazyImage = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy_img');
        addEventListener("scroll", function () {
            lazyImage.forEach(element => {
                let elementS = element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
                    elementDv = window.innerHeight + window.innerHeight / 2;
                if (elementS < elementDv && elementS > 0) {
                    element.src = element.getAttribute('data-src');
                }
            });

        }, true)

    }
    lazyLoad();
```