# Estilo CSS Youtube

Tags: html, css

Sei que a pergunta esta fora do escopo, não tenho pontos o suficiente para posta no outro fórum da stack, se alguém puder mudar para a área certa agradeço.

Como e feito esse tipo de estilo durante o carregamento da pagina?

[image: Como se faz isso?]

Comment: não tinha visto, obrigado por informar. Vou da uma olhada ;)

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158683/5878

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar esse conteúdo,era o que eu precisava para resolver meu problema :)